# Properly displaying thumbnails with the_post_thumbnail()

Tags: php, wordpress, thumbnails

I have created a custom post type named **bateau** in functions.php. I also created a page where all the posts that belong to the **bateau** custom post type are displayed, showing some of the most important fields. Finally, when I click on one of those posts, a link sends me to the related custom post page, i.e. a particular type of boat.

The custom post **bateau** has its own custom fields, a thumbnail, and also its custom taxonomies.

I want to retrieve and display, when I'm on the page of a particular boat,  not only the most important but all its custom fields, its thumbnail and its taxonomy.

So, in the functions.php, I have written this filter :

```
add_filter('the_content','add_text');

    function add_text($text) {

        global $post;
        $text = "";

        if($post->post_type == 'bateau') { 

        $text.= "<h1 class=\"bateau-entry-title\">".get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'bateau_nom', true )."</h1>";
        return $text;
        }
    }
```

It works fine, provided that I don't write plain HTML text within closing and opening PHP tags, i.e. it only works if I wrap all the HTML in a PHP text var. If I don't do so, the content is also displayed at the beginning of the header, not once, but twice. Strange, isn't it ?

If I add this line :

```
$text.= "<img class=\"thumb\" src=\"the_post_thumbnail();
```

the thumbnail displays properly in the "article"...but, guess what, also at the beginning of the header, not once, but twice !!! I just can't find why the thumbnail behaves like this. Anyone can help please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Wordpress, the page you called:

> when I'm on the page of a particular boat

is called `single`. instead of putting a filter on `the_content` using

```
add_filter('the_content','add_text');
```

you would better add whatever you want to the loop. To do so, you may create a file called `single-bateau.php` (this is a protocol, so you need to name it exactly as this) in your current theme's root directory and there you may have your loop:

```
if(have_posts()){
    while(have_posts()){
        the_post();
        the_title();
        if( has_post_thumbnail() ){
            the_post_thumbnail( $thumb_size );
        }
        the_taxonomies();
        the_category();
        the_tags();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need the `img` tag if you're using `the_post_thumbnail()`.

Try doing something like:

```
if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) 
    the_post_thumbnail();
```

Comment: This is not an answer to the question. please read the question carefully